# Overriding Controller Routing

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, routes

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 and I'm looking to dynamically choose which controller handles a particular request.

For example, the user might request `/ControllerName/ActionName/`, but I want to first look and see if in my source I have a controller `/CustomCodeDirecotry/ControllerName/ActionName`. If I have that controller, then use that to process the request. If I don't then go ahead and use the requested controller.

The key in this is that I don't want the user to know that they were handed off to a different url.

Comment: Don't you think this might be extra cost?.

Comment: I'll be sure to run it through a load test environment. But I wouldn't have thought that it would cost much. This is similar as to how MVC works. I've seen View Engines that do something similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end the answer to this question was to provide a namespace when mapping routes. Specifically:

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Default",
url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
namespaces: new[] { "MvcSite.Special.Controllers" });
```

I found my answer [here](http://ngeor.net/2013/12/using-controllers-with-the-same-name-in-asp-net-mvc/)